# Simulating response timeouts with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Suppose I have a client that continually requests streams from a service, and I want automate testing it. So, as part of the test, I create a service that returns a stream. The following code snippet constructs the response and returns it:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StreamContent(fstream);
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = mediaType;
return response;
```

This works for the success case where the client calls the API and gets a response in a timely manner. But I also want to simulate some timeout failures.

If I want to simulate timeouts before any part of the response is returned, i can simply add a *Thread.Sleep()* before return *response*.

My question is: **how can I simulate the timeout case where the service has already started return *response*?** I would like to simulate the service timing out after the response headers have been sent, but before the entirety of *fstream* is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this?

```
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Buffer = false;
response.AddHeader("SomeHeader","SomeValue");
response.Write("Some body text.");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(WEB_SERVER_TIMEOUT_VALUE + 1);
```